# Compiling Python project with all libs

Tags: python-2.7, bytecode, cpython

I have a project that consists of 1 source file and ~10 resource files (fonts). It uses built-in libraries and some 3rd party ones (numpy, scipy, pyBrain, pillow). Is it possible to make all source code and required libraries into one file or a bunch of compiled files, so I can launch it on every CPython with same version without need to install libraries?
AFAIK, it's called static linking in other langs.

Comment: You don't really compile Python. Bytecode is just a (nonportable) implementation detail. Also, some of the libraries you mentioned are written in C.

Comment: So, no easy way to make it?